# PHPUnit Mocks vs PHP parameter constrains

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm not sure if it's the proper place for such question since it's rather theoretical than the specific code sample but I'll ask anyway.

So, at some point PHP introduced type constrains in function definition (except basic types of course), i.e.

```
class A {
   public $value;
}

function foo($someInt, A $a) {...}
```

What make me wondering is if PHPUnit mocks can be used in such situation:

```
class functionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testFoo() {
       $mockA = $this->getMockBuilder('A')->getMock();

       $this->assertEquals('some result', foo(1, $mockA));
    }
}
```

Would such call be accepted when the test runs (ofc. I skipped includes and stuff to keep it simple).

And the more interesting question: if yes, then how is it implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be working, PHPUnit will mock your object. This mocked object will dynamically extends the base Object you want to mock.